# Number of connections per client in L4 vs. L7 Load balancing

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I am reading the [faq for HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/loadbalancing-faq/).

It mentions that **the layer 4 connection is established between the** client and the server.

And in the next section, **the layer 7 load-balancer acts as a proxy, which means it maintains two TCP connections: one with the client and one with the server.**

I thought even the L4 LB will maintain 2 connections - one with the client and one with the server.

**Why is that not the case?**

Answer (score 2):

More load balancer techniques exist than just proxies; that is a FAQ for load balancing in general. Read HAProxy's [intro.txt](https://www.haproxy.org/download/2.1/doc/intro.txt) particularly the survey on the topic "Quick introduction to load balancing and load balancers".

HAProxy is, well, a proxy. In TCP mode it links an incoming and outgoing socket like you were expecting. Again from intro.txt:

```
  - a TCP proxy : it can accept a TCP connection from a listening socket,
    connect to a server and attach these sockets together allowing traffic to
    flow in both directions
```

At layer 4, it is also possible to forward the original flow to several different next hops based on just IP + TCP. You could call these packet-based load balancers fancy routers. Which isn't what TCP proxies like HAProxy do.

L7, at the application layer, enables many more features. Near-universally implemented as a proxy.

---

Some designs have both L4 and L7 load balancers, for redundancy and scalability. Combines extremely fast (usually) stateless L4 with the fancy features of a L7 proxy.

For an example of this, have a look at Vincent Bernat's lab [Multi-tier load-balancing with Linux](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2018-multi-tier-loadbalancer). ECMP routers, L4 to get the desired connection routing, L7 with the fancy features in front of the backends.

Comment: Is the gist of the your answer that it is possible to have 2 different TCP connection for L4 load balancer as well? If so, is the vice-versa also true wherein 1 single TCP connection between client and server when there's a L7 load balancer in between?

Comment: My answer is essentially, do not conflate layer 4 load balancing with proxying. There are L4 load balancers that are not proxies, the lab I linked to built one with keepalived on top of IPVS.  And, there are L4 load balancers that are proxies, such as HAProxy in TCP mode. HAProxy in specific you can assume to terminate a frontend connection and start a backend connection because, well, proxy is in the name.